# How can I make the first row of a SAS dataset the variable names?

Tags: sas, rename

I have an already imported dataset where the first row contains the variable names.  I know that typically when importing a dataset you use getnames = yes.  However, if the data is already imported how can I make the first row the variable names using a data step?

Data looks like:

```
         A         B         C 
1      Name 1   Name 2     Name 3
2        2        4          66
3        3        5          6
```

Comment: If the variable is numeric it will have to be converted to character.  Are you sure?  What is the purpose?

Comment: This is a bad idea, consider adding labels instead?

Comment: If you're trying to export a file with both labels and variable names, in two separate rows, here's one method: https://gist.github.com/statgeek/ae153e40af0d35dce02d1c8102ff3b94

Answer (score 3):

Since reading the names as data probably made all of your variables character you can try just transposing the data twice to fix it.  That will work well for small datasets.

So the first transpose will place the current name into the `_NAME_` variable and convert each row into a column.  The second proc transpose can drop the original name and use the first row (new `COL1` variable) as the names.

```
proc transpose data=have out=wide ;
 var _all_;
run;

proc transpose data=wide(drop=_name_ rename=(col1=_name_)) out=want(drop=_name_ _label_);
   var col:;
   id _name_;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the already imported data is that all the numeric data was likely placed in a character variables because the 'first row' of data seen by the import process contained some character data, and drove the inference for automatic column construction.

Regardless, you will need to construct renaming pairs *old-name*=*new-name* for each variables that has to be renamed. The new-name being in row 1 makes it possible to `transpose` that row to arrange those name parts as data.  SQL with `:into` and `separated by` can populate a macro variable for use in a `proc datasets` step that performs the column renaming without rewriting the entire data set.  Finally, a DATA step with `modify` can `remove` a row in place, again, without rewriting the entire data set.

```
filename sandbox temp;

data _null_;
  file sandbox;
  put 'A,B,C';
  put 'Name 1, Name 2, Name 3';
  put '2,4,66';
  put '3,5,6';
run;

proc import datafile=sandbox dbms=csv replace out=work.oops;
run;

proc transpose data=oops(obs=1) out=renames;
var _all_;
run;           

proc sql noprint;
  select cats(_name_,"=",compress(col1,,"KN"))
  into :renames separated by ' '
  from renames;

%put NOTE: &=renames;

proc datasets nolist lib=work;
  modify oops;
  rename &renames;
run;

data oops;
  modify oops;
  remove;
  stop;
run;

%let syslast=oops;
```